# what separates us from our identity to another person

Tags: philosophy

I am indian.

You are Americans .

Our identity  divide human beings?

I am hindu.

You are muslim.

Our identity divide human beings?

I am buddhist monk.

I am ordinary human.

I am hindu.

I am muslim.

Hindu  hates Muslim  beacuse   i am hindu .

Muslim hate hindu  beacuse you are muslim.

Indian hate pakistan beacuse I am indian.

Pakistan hate indian beacuse he is pakistan.

Every one carry identity.

Identity create conflict 
Conflict create war

Comment: Untill Enlightenment ,we all are same ,i.e., "Children of Thirst & Ego , Served by Crave , having Nationality of 12 Sense-Bases & having Delusions of Permanence & Annihilation ". Can be said ,till enlightenment ,only Ignorance is our identity in various Combinations .Post enlightenment ,no-self ,no-identity ... ,no-ignorance.

Comment: Book answer..No need ..buddhism answer no need....Only need your experience

Answer (score 1):

> Hindu hates Muslim beacuse i am hindu .
>
> Muslim hate hindu beacuse you are muslim.
>
> Indian hate pakistan beacuse I am indian.
>
> Pakistan hate indian beacuse he is pakistan.
>
> Every one carry identity.
>
> Identity create conflict

Identity doesn't create conflict, clinging to a sense of self-identity does. It's a subtle difference, but it's an important difference nonetheless. If it was true that "identity creates conflict", there would be absolutely zero Hindu who loves Muslims, zero Muslim who loves Hindus, zero Indian who loves Pakistanis, etc. But quite the contrary, any "self-identified" Hindu, Muslim, Christian, Buddhist, Taoist, etc. who sincerely and honestly practices their faith would treat one another like brothers and sisters in the same family.

Comment: I think. No need any identity.

Answer (score 0):

> What separates us from identifying with another person?

The fear of the unknown, dosa(fear) and avija(not knowing).

The jealous comparing mind that is  lobha(greed).

Nothing in actuality admits that anything is separate.

What separates us is our belief and perception that we are separate.

Comment: You are right. Our belief and perception separate human beings

Answer (score 0):

The scriptures teach conflict comes from craving, as follows:

> *Craving is a cause of seeking. Seeking is a cause of gaining material
>   possessions. Gaining material possessions is a cause of assessing. Assessing is a cause of desire and lust. Desire and lust is a cause of
>   attachment. Attachment is a cause of possessiveness. Possessiveness is
>   a cause of stinginess. Stinginess is a cause of safeguarding. Owing to
>   safeguarding, many bad, unskillful things come to be: taking up the
>   rod and the sword, quarrels, arguments, and fights, accusations,
>   divisive speech and lies.*

Therefore, it is immoral craving or, occasionally, wholesome desire, that separates people. For example:

- Indians struggle to understand Buddhism (because the the celibate Buddha & his Arahant disciples probably drained India of enlightenment genetics) so Buddhists must be patient with Indians. This gives rise to identity due to hope.
- Americans engage in imperialism, destroy many nations & murder many people so humane people don't appreciate them. This gives rise to identity due to hoping.
- Muslims can be fundamentalists & imperialists so Hindus are apprehensive of them. This gives rise to identity due to worry.
- Buddhist monks have to twist the Dhamma into mundane dhamma so ordinary person (puthujjana) feels they are a Buddhist. This gives rise to identity due to hoping.
- Hindu hates Muslim because (Turkic covert) Muslim has history of violence & conquering. This gives rise to identity due to wishing.
- Indian hate Pakistan because Wasim Akram was better at cricket than Sourav Ganguly and because Benazir Bhutto was better looking than Indira Gandhi. This gives rise to identity due to craving.

Therefore conflict & division comes from craving & desire, both wholesome & unwholesome. And then craving & desire gives rise to identity.

Answer (score 0):

No india,No pakistan,No america , no earth

No hindu, no Muslim,No buddhism ,No  human beings

No identity!

No division!

No conflict!

No war

Now question  is

How to make identity

Comment: No earth , no planet , no human being .Earth ,planet ,human being is also an identity & taken from book not experience. Experience :::::: We all are just animals feeding each other ,including earth too(it eats dead ones, ashes).

Comment: You are right bro.. I edit my answer  no human and no earth..

Comment: Thanks  for "no earth " and "human"